# How can I find the code that produces a certain error message (e.g. "Sorry, can not load CMS user account.")

Tags: error-page

When confirming donation I'm receiving the following error message "Sorry, can not load CMS user account." How can I track down which file this message is generated in?

Other details: I'm working through the vanco payment processor 4.1 code to make it work with 4.4 CiviCRM. The URL is similar to: www.domain.org/civicrm/contribute/transact

Answer (score 4):

This particular phrase appears to be in these files:

```
./CRM/Utils/System/Drupal.php
./CRM/Utils/System/Drupal6.php
```

Here are two ways you can search for specific phrases within the codebase:

**1) GREP**

Using this command from the base `civicrm` directory:

`>  grep -R "Sorry, can not load CMS user account." ./`

**2) GITHUB**

And if you don't have a command line handy, you can do the same on [the CiviCRM GitHub page](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core) with the "Search this repository" function at the top ([using the quotation marks to search for the exact phrase](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%22Sorry%2C%20can%20not%20load%20CMS%20user%20account%22)):

[image: Github search repository]

Comment: Thank you, verified it as CRM_Utils_System_Drupal, line 726

Comment: Lesson learned, look beyond CiviCRM code base when CMS user is noted.

Comment: Glad to help. Technically it is still in the CiviCRM codebase, just in a portion of it that only applies to Drupal in this case. I find `grep` saves me a lot of time in a situation like this.